# Periodicity executate for web scraping with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Here is my idea and my early work.

#### *My target*

- Fetch 1-hour resolution air pollution data from China's goverment continuously.
- The website's data which collected from the monitor sites over the country update per hour .

#### *My Code*

Now, I can grab the useful information for a single hour. Here is my code:

1. *Input the website links for different pollution(co,no2,pm10, etc)*

   ```
   html_co = urllib.urlopen("http://www.pm25.in/api/querys/co.json?city=beijing&token=5j1znBVAsnSf5xQyNQyq").read().decode('utf-8')
   html_no2 = urllib.urlopen("http://www.pm25.in/api/querys/no2.json?city=beijing&token=5j1znBVAsnSf5xQyNQyq").read().decode('utf-8')
   html_pm10 = urllib.urlopen("http://www.pm25.in/api/querys/pm10.json?city=beijing&token=5j1znBVAsnSf5xQyNQyq").read().decode('utf-8')
   ```
2. *Get the content of the html doc.*

   ```
   soup_co = BeautifulSoup(html_co)
   soup_no2 = BeautifulSoup(html_no2)
   soup_pm10 = BeautifulSoup(html_pm10)
   ```
3. *Extract the useful information from the whole content.*

   ```
   l = soup_co.p.get_text() 
   co= json.loads(l) 
   l = soup_no2.p.get_text() 
   no2= json.loads(l) 
   l = soup_pm10.p.get_text() 
   pm10= json.loads(l)
   ```
4. *Tight the raw data into neat Pandas.Dataframe.*

   ```
   data = {"time":[],"station":[],"code":[],"co":[],"no2":[],"pm10":[]}
   for i in range(0,len(pm10)-1,1):
       ## 'station' is the monitor station's name in Chinese
       data["station"].append(co[i]["position_name"])
       data["time"].append(co[i]["time_point"])
       data["co"].append(co[i]["co"])
       ## 'code' is the monitor station's index
       data["code"].append(co[i]["station_code"])
       data["no2"].append(no2[i]["no2"])
       data["pm10"].append(pm10[i]["pm10"])
   ```

#### *My result*

*Some pre-explanation*

- Ignore the chinese character in the table.
- I only grab one city(Beijing here)'s data, and index from 0-11 notify that Beijing has 12 monitor site.
- The columns 'co'/'NO2'/'PM10' represent the concentration of these air pollutants.
  http://i8.tietuku.com/cf59fbec6f89566d.png

#### *My problem*

Now, I can grab the web data manually according my code above. But, I want to **achieve the working flow below hourly  automatically**.

Hour i

- Execute the code
- (1) Grab the data for Hour i's air pollutants data from website;
- (2) Save the data into .csv based on the true date(like 20160101.csv)

After one hour.

- Execute the code
- (1) Grab the data for Hour i+1's air pollutants data from website;
- (2) Save the data into .csv based on the true date.
    if it's the same day liken to hour i --> same .csv(like 2016-01-01.csv)
    if the present day has past --> creat a new .csv(like 2016-01-02.csv)

I havn't done these kind of stuff before. Can somebody offer me some advice?
So, I can get an useful data scraping tool run in the background and I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I assume you have the above bundled in a `python` script and it also writes a file with the result data. First for the automatic execution: What operating system are you using? When it's linux or MacOS, I suggest you take a look at the `cron` documentation. There are numerous documentation sites out there and your last resort would be `$ man cron` in a shell. Regarding the update of a `.csv`, I would rather point you to a light database option. Maybe you would like to check the `python` docs on `SQLLite3`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about your program just waiting around for an hour you could do:

```
def func(): 
    print('Time has passed')

while True:   
    delay = 1 * 60 * 60 # x hrs * 60 mins * 60 sec (waiting time in hrs)
    func()              # run your code
    time.sleep(delay)   # wait
```

This is v basic and will not allow you to do anything while your program sleeps.